# Replace and Merge "Duplicates" From a HashSet

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, duplicates, hashset

I have a `HashSet<T>` of a hierarchical object in C# 4.0. The main key is an int, but there are occasionally secondary keys which are duplicated. I would like to merge the entries with duplicated secondary keys.  In this example the secondary key is Name:

```
struct Element
{
  int ID;
  string Name;
  List<int> Children;
  List<int> Parents;

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return ID;
  }
}

HashSet<Element> elements = new HashSet<Element>();

// Example Elements
elements.Add(1, "Apple", Children = {10, 11, 12}, Parents = {13,14,15});
elements.Add(2, "Banana", Children = {20, 21, 22}, Parents = {23,24,25});
elements.Add(3, "Apple", Children = {30, 31, 32}, Parents = {33,34,35});
elements.Add(4, "Food", Children = {1, 2, 3}, Parents = {});
```

The goal is to remove the 3rd entry {3, "Apple",...} and then update and merge the Parent and Children references in the other remaining elements; the end result should be this:

```
{ 1, "Apple", Children = { 10, 11, 12, 30, 31, 32 }, Parents = { 13,14,15, 33, 34, 35 }}
{ 2, "Banana", Children = { 20, 21, 22 }, Parents = { 23,24,25 }}
{ 4, "Food", Children = {1, 2}, Parents = {} }
```

Here is what I have so far, but I can't figure out the best way to update the HashSet in place. I start by copying the HashSet so that I can do deletes while iterating. First I find the duplicates.  If there are duplicates I want to update and them remove them from the copy.  That is where I get stuck.  Once I've updated the duplicates, I want to remove them, and prevent processing them again with a skip list:

```
var copy = new HashSet<Element>(Elements);
HashSet<int> skip = new HashSet<int>();
foreach (var e in Elements)
{
  if (!skip.Contains(e.ID)
  {
    var duplicates = Elements.Where(x => e.Name == x.Name && e.ID != x.ID);
    if (duplicates.Any())
    {           
      foreach (var d in duplicates)
      {
        // Iterate copy and update Parent and Children references
        // How do I do this part? 
      }

      // Remove the duplicates from the copied list
      copy.RemoveWhere(x => duplicates.Select(x => x.ID)
                                      .Contains(x.ID));

      // Don't process the duplicates again
      skip.UnionWith(duplicates);
    } 
  }
}
return copy;
```

I'm stuck at this point.  Also, is there a slick way to do this with Linq?

**Update:** The list is already like this, I don't have control over the initial contents.  I suppose I could create a new wrapper that has a better Add method to prevent duplication.

Comment: What's the integer ID used for? Could you use a Dictionary<string,Element> where string is the fruit name?

Comment: using `HashSet` here doesn't add any value to your algorithm or solution. `Element`s need to implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, but since your key is not even an `Element`, then it is totally useless. You can get a better result by a `Dictionary<int, Element>` where the key is the same as `Element.ID`.

Comment: `var copy = Elements;` does not create a copy. Just another reference to the very same thing.

Comment: @SinaIravanian that doesn't quite meet the need, he needs a composite key. Maybe separating the children information into a separate record, and maintaining the key as part of the actual element?

Comment: @jcolebrand I think he can achieve creating a composite key, by implementing `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for the `Element` struct. Just checking the fields that require to be the same.

Comment: But he needs to add logic to handle adding them to the hash/dictionary. So if the element already exists he doesn't override them.

Comment: Added an edit. The distinction between HashSet and Dictionary isn't particularly concerning to me. Suppose there is no key and I just have a list with possible duplicates of Name.  The problem of merging Children and Parents is there.  Creating a new "list/dictionary/hashset" by doing adds from the old list with a protected Add is an option. Is there a cleaner way to do it inplace?

Comment: @jcolebrand Absolutely true. All I meant is that `Hashset<Element>` is no more functionality than e.g., `List<Element>`. Since `Element` does not implement `GetHashCode` then all instances of `Element` is considered distinct (because they have distinct object references), even if they contain exactly the same data.

Comment: Hence he needs to check on the indexes, and yes, I agree, GetHashCode should work for that. But the native Object GetHashCode that everything inherits from will work. He has two options as I see it: standardize the key, or as you suggest override the GetHashCode. My way is more intentful, I think, to the reader. Yours is more pure.

Comment: See [Enumerable.Except() accepting IEqualityComparer<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to:

1. Remove elements with the same Name
2. Merge the removed elements' Children and Parents lists to the remaining element
3. In Children and Parents lists, replace references to the removed IDs with the remaining element's ID

These can be accomplished with the following code:

```
// Find all duplicated elements and remove them
var duplicates = Elements.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                         .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                         .SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(e => e.ID)
                                           .Skip(1)
                                           .Select(e => new { Element = e, NewID = x.Min(y => y.ID) }))
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.Element.ID, x => new { x.Element, x.NewID });
Elements.ExceptWith(duplicates.Values.Select(x => x.Element));

// Update the Children and Parents of each remaining element
foreach (var element in Elements)
{
    var removed = duplicates.Where(x => x.Value.Element.Name == element.Name);

    var mergedChildren = element.Children.Union(removed.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Element.Children))
                                         .Select(x => duplicates.ContainsKey(x) ? duplicates[x].NewID : x)
                                         .Distinct().ToList();
    element.Children.Clear();
    element.Children.AddRange(mergedChildren);


    var mergedParents = element.Parents.Union(removed.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Element.Parents))
                                       .Select(x => duplicates.ContainsKey(x) ? duplicates[x].NewID : x)
                                       .Distinct().ToList();
    element.Parents.Clear();
    element.Parents.AddRange(mergedParents);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this single field element.

```
struct Element
{
  int ID;
  string Name;
  List<int> Children;
  List<int> Parents;
  Bool duplicate;
}

HashSet<Element> Elements = new HashSet();

// Example Elements
Elements.Add(1, "Apple", Children = {10, 11, 12}, Parents = {13,14,15}, duplicate = false);
Elements.Add(2, "Banana", Children = {20, 21, 22}, Parents = {23,24,25}, duplicate = false);
Elements.Add(3, "Apple", Children = {30, 31, 32}, Parents = {33,34,35}, duplicate = false);
Elements.Add(4, "Food", Children = {1, 2, 3}, Parents = {}, duplicate = false);
```

As you iterate on your copy, mark "duplicate" to true. Or add a "deleted" element so you don't reprocess. Or whatever. The point is, add one more element. You can always copy the element and create new when adding.

To add to Sina's comments earlier, you could have a key like thus:

```
class ElementKey {
  int ID;
  string Name;
}

class Element {
  ElementKey Key;
  List<int> Children;
  List<int> Parents;
  ProcessFlagSet flags;
}

class ProcessFlagSet {
  bool Processed;
  bool Duplicate;
}

Dictionary<ElementKey,Element> ...
```

And then you can remove all the elements from ProcessFlagSet later for easy refactoring needs. They'll break compilation till they're removed if you don't need them.

Lastly, I want to recommend creating your own Add method here. I want you to consider passing in the element to be added, then check to see if the key exists on add. This saves you a step.

Comment: I edited the question.  The data in the initial HashSet already exists and its big.  Even with a new Add() wrapper it would still be necessary to iterate through each element's Parents and Children and do the merge for the newly added element.

Comment: It would be nice if the initial list didn't contain these duplicates, but it does.  Is the best way really to remove them by re-adding them to another ADT?

Comment: No, the best thing to do is to remove them on the initial insert. If there is no way to remove them on the initial insert, then a cleanup operation is the only alternative. However, I'm also curious if you would see a speedup by changing the struct to a class, because of the way struct's are consumed in memory.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
var temp = Elements.GroupBy(e => e.Name)
                   .Select(g => new Element
                   {
                       ID = g.OrderBy(e => e.ID).First().ID,
                       Name = g.Key,
                       Children = g.SelectMany(e => e.Children).ToList(),
                       Parents = g.SelectMany(e => e.Parents).ToList()
                   });
var duplicates = Elements.Where(e => !temp.Any(t => t.ID == e.ID))
                         .Select(e => e.ID)
                         .Distinct();
Elements = new HashSet<Element>(temp);
foreach (Element e in Elements)
{
    e.Children.RemoveAll(i => duplicates.Contains(i));
    e.Parents.RemoveAll(i => duplicates.Contains(i));
}
```

As far as I understood you only need to group all elements by the `Name`, then choose the lowest `ID` and join `Children` and `Parents`. Clearly this is done by this query.

Comment: This is close, but the Children and Parent lists will end up with orphaned higher IDs that no longer map to anything.

Comment: This doesn't quite work either. I need a find and replace before the move. I've been messing around with this for too long and I can't see the forest for the trees at this point.  This is really close though (I think). Thanks.